# Add Comments on selected text Froala WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plugins, comments, froala

I'm using Froala WYSIWYG Editor v3.2.4
We got requirement of commenting on selected text justlike TinyMCE (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/comments-2/), CKEditor, Google docs etc.

Is there any possibility to add comments to selection of text in Froala editor?

Comment: Did you come up with any solution or do you have any information or URLs for us? Thanks!

Comment: Not yet @tommygun